# Completion and linting in the editor for Python files will not work during current session, or stopped working

Tags: python, warnings, spyder

I don't know how to repair the error. Every time I open Spyder the warnings shows up and restarting the aplication doesn't solve the problem.

If you can help me I would appreciate it.

**Spyder Completion Warning**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the dialog says you need to check your firewall or antivirus since probably one of them is stopping/preventing the launching of the process that Spyder uses to provide completions and linting. To check if either your firewall or antivirus is causing the problem you could try to deactivate/disable them **temporarly** and try to launch Spyder again. If that helps then you need to create rules to allow Python processes.

Another option, if you are ok without having those services (completion and linting), is to ignore this message and select the `Don't show again` checkbox to prevent seen it again.

For more details regarding completion and linting services that Spyder provides you can check the documentation here:

- For Spyder 4: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/4/faq.html#troubleshooting-completion
- For SPyder 5: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/faq.html#troubleshooting-completion

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate, I visited de link and did what they said and didn't work.  I think the problem is my  antivirus

Comment: No problem, glad to help and know that at least you have a more specific idea of what could be the problem now

Answer (score 4):

Disabling the firewall and antivirus didn't work for me. I was able to fix this issue by [resetting Spyder](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/troubleshooting/basic-first-aid.html). In the Anaconda prompt, enter:

```
spyder --reset
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was caused by incompatible versions and fixed by (here for Python 3.10)

```
python3.10 -m pip install -U python-language-server
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case helped:

```
pip install spyder -U
```